# Empathy won't login my Hangout account

Tags: login, empathy, google

It's just that, there's no error or anything, sometimes (not always) when I try to login to my Google account to chat using Hangout it just won't. It's like it tries to log in but it can't and then it says "Change your presence to see contacts here" and if you click on "Go Online" it is just the same.
Sometimes restarting the whole system works, sometimes it doesn't.
I was using Pidgin before Empathy, and I never had this problem, but I really don't like Pidgin so I'd like Empathy to work for me.
I search for this question but didn't find this particular case.

---

It's been working flawlessly for a week now, I don't know if they fixed it or it's just luck, because it worked sometimes before, but randomly.

Comment: Restarting the computer usually fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Google account security and generate an "app password", this should allow empathy or other 3rd party clients to authenticate.